# bootstrap 4 card deck with expand / collapse content - would like the expanded content to just affect current card

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have several card decks that respond nicely. In each case I have expand/collapse content that also works nicely. When I click on expand, it expands the card and shows the previously hidden content. When I click on collapse, it returns to showing just the card's "headline" content.

Unfortunately this isn't quite the behaviour I'd like. The big problem is that when I expand one card, all the other cards in the row expand as well. Their hidden content doesn't show but I get a large blank area (the card background).

When the card deck is static content, it pushes the subsequent content down. This isn't a big issue. But when the content is dynamic (created with javascript from an XML file), I have to use z-index to elevate above the subsequent content. In this case the empty expanded card sections end up obscuring the content below them. I could live with it being just the currently expanded card since that would only obscure less than 1/4 of the content, but with all the cards expanding, it covers pretty much everything.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body bg-light" id="1">
        <h4 class="card-title">March&nbsp;27, 2020</h4>
        <p>
           <img class="card-img-top" src="images/somephoto.jpeg" alt='some description' />
          <a href="#c1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c1">
          <span class="collapsed">more...</span><span class="expanded">...less</span>
          </a>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="c1">
          <p>some content</p>
        </div>
      </div
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body bg-light" id="2">
        <h4 class="card-title">August&nbsp;19, 2019</h4>
        <p>
           <img class="card-img-top" src="images/anotherphoto.jpeg" alt='another description' />
          <a href="#c2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c2">
          <span class="collapsed">more...</span><span class="expanded">...less</span>
          </a>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="c2">
    ...
```

Can anyone suggest a way for me to get what I want - just having the one card expand?

Comment: @ Gary Dale: if possible, post the whole code for the cards section. How many cards do you use and in which form/structure do you want to display them on different screen sizes?

Comment: The code I've posted is sufficient (just add the closing divs) to demonstrate the problem.  The number of cards varies but they generally display one to a row on phones with more on larger devices.

The problem is with expanded div - when one card body expands, they all expand to that size (but only the expanded card body shows its content - the others are just the background).

Answer (score 0):

I believe coordinating the same height across multiple cards is a feature of the `card-deck` class. Try using the `card-columns` class and see if that works with your content as desired. Each column will expand independently, but the cards could have different heights depending on the content. Here's the documentation for [bootstrap's card-columns component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#card-columns).

Here's an example:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body bg-light" id="1">
            <h4 class="card-title">March&nbsp;27, 2020</h4>
            <p>
               <img class="card-img-top" src="images/somephoto.jpeg" alt='some description' />
              <a href="#c1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c1">
              <span class="collapsed">more...</span><span class="expanded">...less</span>
              </a>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="c1">
              <p>some content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body bg-light" id="2">
            <h4 class="card-title">August&nbsp;19, 2019</h4>
            <p>
               <img class="card-img-top" src="images/anotherphoto.jpeg" alt='another description' />
              <a href="#c2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c2">
              <span class="collapsed">more...</span><span class="expanded">...less</span>
              </a>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="c2">
              <p>More content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want the cards to be the same height when the extra content is collapsed. That's why I chose to use a card-deck. I'm just not liking having the cards stay the same height when one card has expanded content.